# Staff rota scheduling software

Tags: database, reporting, scheduling

My partner runs a pub and spends ages every week designing a staff rota for her bar and kitchen by hand on a sheet of paper.
I'd like to drag her into this century and get her using some software that helps speed up the process.

She has around 10 employees (3 kitchen, 7 bar). I'd like to be able to put these into the software (with their respective hourly rates) and set up blocks of hours. Then have the ability to be able to just drag and drop people into these blocks of hours. It would then display the total week staffing cost.

Even better would be the facility to set up rules against the blocks. So for example, there must be 2 kitchen staff on between 12 & 4 on a Sunday and have a visual representation as to whether the rules have been satisfied (so the shift will be red if not met, green if it has).

The rota could then be saved and emailed/WhatsApp/SMS to all employees. Having access to a year's worth of data could be useful but not essential (but the ability to append to a csv every week would get around this). The ability to be able to report on how many hours each employee has done per week would be useful.

She's a bit apprehensive about the benefits, so I'd need to keep the costs to a minimum. Maybe something in the region of a couple of hundred pounds per year at the most.

If there is a tool out there that I could use to create my own, I'd be open to looking into that too. I have a very basic grasp of programming. I've considered a spreadsheet but I'd like something a little more robust.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of scheduler rota/roster builder systems that could be of use, provided appropriate constraints entered. See these examples:

- [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/)
- [ABC Roster](http://www.abc-roster.com/)

I suggest you play with them yourself, to see what would work better for you. Both are free, and have some examples.

Comment: ABC Roster looks perfect for what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Give a chance to [TimeClock Kiwi](https://timeclock.kiwi/).

It is a web-based platform that allows companies and individuals to track the time they spend on various tasks, projects, and clients.

**Features:**

- time tracking
- project management
- invoicing
- reporting
- team collaboration tools

Comment: Your answer has been flag as low quality and might be removed; please have a look at [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/23377) for some tips on how to improve it.